# How to convert a group of video files using FFMPEG?

Tags: shell, command-line, ffmpeg

I have several video files in a directory and I want to convert all of them into other video formats.
Is there any way that I can convert all of them in just one go using FFMPEG. I mean without having to make a shell script for doing so.

Comment: What about a simple `for` loop? `for i in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$i" …;done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a for loop of your shell of choice. This task is so simple, you can just use the prompt, there's no need to create a shell script.

Here is the one-liner as an example for the widely-used bash (and compatible):

```
for i in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$i" … ;done
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did such a conversion starting from Marco's solution. I added changing the file extension, in my case, from .mp4 to .mp3:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec:a mp3 "mp3/${i%.mp4}.mp3";done
```